# LIMBO doesn't detect my Shader Model 3.0

Tags: 12.04, wine, gpu

I recently bought the Humble Indie Bundle V and installed LIMBO with the Ubuntu Software Center. When I launch it, it says it doesn't detect Shader Model 3.0. I read about Wine having issues detect Shader Model 3.0 and that running LIMBO in an older version might help. But I'm still not sure. Is there another fix for it? My GPU is a ATi Mobility Radeon 9600.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I dont get this?!

Comment: @Syzygy The question is: How to overcome the Shader Model 3.0 error?

Comment: Does your graphics card support shader model 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R300) shows that your GPU supports upto shader model 2.0. So I think you won't get the shader model 3.0 support with this hardware anyway.